# How to sort an array wrt to another one

Tags: java, sorting

What will the Java program be to perform the below task?

Given two arrays called `a` and `c`. I need to sort `a` with respect to `c`.

For example, if `a={2,3,4}` and `c={-1,2,1}`.
Sorting a with regards to c will produce `{2,4,3}`

I did it in C++ using `pair<>`. How do I do the same in Java using inbuilt features?

Comment: Then learn Java

Comment: You could always use a 2d array or a custom `Pair` class and sort accordingly.

Comment: @Satya I did it using treeMap but it doesn't allow duplicates.

Comment: @Thomas can you please elaborate on who to do it using 2d array without manually writing the sort function.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: You wouldn't manually write the _sort_ method but you'd probably need a comparator.

Comment: Alternatively, if the elements in `c` are unique, try a `TreeMap<Integer, Integer>` with the `c` elements being the key.

Comment: @Thomas it can have duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same in Java:

```
class Pair<A, C extends Comparable<C>> implements Comparable<Pair<A,C>> {
    public final A a;
    public final C c;

    Pair(A a, C c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair<A, C> o) {
        return c.compareTo(o.c);
    }
}
```

...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Pair<>(2,-1));
    list.add(new Pair<>(3,2));
    list.add(new Pair<>(4,1));
    Collections.sort(list);
    list.stream().forEach((pair) -> {
        System.out.println(pair.a + " " + pair.c);
    });
}
```

UPDATE:

Or, more simply:

```
class Pair<A, C> {
    public final A a;
    public final C c;

    Pair(A a, C c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.c = c;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Pair<>(2,-1));
    list.add(new Pair<>(3,2));
    list.add(new Pair<>(4,1));
    Collections.sort(list,
            (Pair<Integer, Integer> o1, Pair<Integer, Integer> o2) -> o1.c.compareTo(o2.c));
    list.stream().forEach((pair) -> {
        System.out.println(pair.a + " " + pair.c);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was quite simple using comparator

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility using arrays directly instead of intermediate data structures.  It's a little bit more complicated (a couple of lines) than would ideally be necessary, but `IntStream` does not provide a `sorted(Comparator)`, so the stream needs to be boxed to sort by the auxiliary array, and then unboxed.

```
int[] a = { 2, 3, 4 };
int[] c = { -1, 2, 1 };

int[] sorted = IntStream.range(0, a.length)
    .boxed()
    .sorted((n1, n2) -> Integer.compare(c[n1], c[n2]))
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    .map(i -> a[i])
    .toArray();
```

The algorithm computes a sorted permutation of `c`, and then outputs that permutation of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4);
    List<Integer> c= Arrays.asList(-1, 2, 1);

    List<Integer> sa = new ArrayList<>(a);
    Collections.sort(sa);

    List<Integer> sc = new ArrayList<>(c);
    Collections.sort(sc);

    List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>(a);
    for (int idx = 0; idx < sc.size(); idx++) {
        b.set(c.indexOf(sc.get(idx)), sa.get(idx));
    }
}
```

The `List<Integer> b` will contain the elements of `a` according the sort order in `c`.

**How it work:**

- we sort the elements of `a`.
- we sort the elements of `c` to identify their absolute position.
- we iterate over each absolute position of sorted `c` and identify the relative position of the element.
- we lookup the element in `a` which corresponds to the same absolute position as the element in `c` and place it to the same relative position as the relative position of the element of `c`.

Comment: What is the complexity of the above algorithm? I think the for loop will have O(n*n). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The methods `List.get(idx)`, `List.set(idx, elem)` have complexity of `O(1)`. The method `List.indexOf(elem)` has complexity of `O(n)`. And the for-loop has complexity `O(n)`. Now the rest is up to you.

Comment: @NishantSharma yes, the loop has `O(n^2)` due to the loop's own `O(n)` and indexOf's `O(n)`. `Collections.sort(...)` has `O(n*log n)` complexity but still the overall complexity will be `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Thomas the answer by Maurice Perry appears to be right with O(nlogn) complexity.

Comment: @NishantSharma yupp, you just have the `O(nlogn)` `Collections.sort()` or `Arrays.sort()` with an appropriate comparator.